# Embed svg causes download of image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, svg

I'm trying to embed svg images in Views in an Asp.Net MVC 3 application, but when I do the browser tries to download the image instead of showing it...

Strangely, I have never experienced this problem when doing the same thing in PHP (CodeIgniter).

Here is the embed code:

```
<embed src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/testproduct/testimage.svg")" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

I have also tried without Url.Content, simply using a leading slash. And I also tried the object element instead, same problem.

The View uses html 5 doctype:

What is wrong here, and how is it possible this could work in PHP but not in this Asp.Net MVC application? I should note that I have only tried it on localhost, but that was the same with PHP, only using Apache instead of the Visual Studio localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer: it had to do with the internal web server in Visual Studio, which didn't handle the Mime type of the SVG images. So basically we had to switch to using IIS 7.5 Express, and then define the Mime type in the web.config file, and then it worked!